# PHP recursiveIteratorIterator: get the sub directories only?

Tags: php, spl, php-5.4

I just want to list the sub dirs in the main dirs by using `RecursiveIteratorIterator`,

```
$array_directories = array(
    'core/controller/',
    'core/model/',
    'core/helper/'
);

foreach($array_directories as $path_directory){

   $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
        if ($fileObject->isDir()) {
            $files[] = $fileObject;
        }
    }


}

print_r($files);
```

result,

```
Array
(
    [0] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => core/controller\webfront
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => webfront
        )

    [1] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => core/model\design
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => design
        )

)
```

But I am after,

```
Array
(
    [0] => core/controller\webfront
    [1] => core/model\design
)
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($fileObject->isDir()) {
    $files[] = $fileObject->getPathname();
}
```